# Excel 2016 index match within specified dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I want to be able to index match id number from two different worksheets and only retrieve dates which fall under specified dates (within past six months from current date).

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet1]

For example,
if worksheet1's id matches worksheet2's id, get the date only if the date falls in specified date.

can some one help me on this?

Comment: sorry worksheets

Answer (score 1):

As for month difference, you might want to consider [DATEDIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c), in which "M" option shall do the trick.

As for accessing cell in different worksheet, you can prepend Sheet Name with exclamation mark to the cell number. For example: "Sheet2!B3" will refer to the B3 cell of worksheet Sheet2. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa) for more info.

To put them together, here is the formula (I am sure there's better alternative somewhere, but this is the one I got):

```
IF(IF(B1-Sheet1!B1>0,DATEDIF(Sheet1!B1,B1,"M"),DATEDIF(B1,Sh‌​eet1!B1,"M"))<=6, Sheet1!B1, "")
```

The *inner if* is checking which order the DATEDIF should be applied depending on which date is earlier. The outer if is checking whether to display the date on sheet one depending on if the months difference is no greater than six months.

Comment: Keith, I apologize for my incomplete answer. Here is my follow-up. 


IF(IF(B1-Sheet1!B1>0,DATEDIF(Sheet1!B1,B1,"M"),DATEDIF(B1,Sheet1!B1,"M"))<=6, Sheet1!B1, "")

The inner if is checking which order the DATEDIF should be applied depending on which date is earlier.

The outer if is checking whether to display the date on sheet one depending on if the months difference is no greater than six months.

Comment: Why not edit your answer, that makes things easier to see.

Comment: Hi Luuklag, thanks for your advice. I will love to improve on it. However, I am new here and not sure how to effectively edit and improve it. Would you advise some direction? Thx!

Comment: Just click the edit button on the bottom left of your post.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I mean... I know how to click on the "edit", but not sure exactly how to edit in order to make it easier to see...

Comment: I just merged my comment into the post. I suppose this is what you meant, @Luuklag?